# Search not showing pagination when query is searched

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm building a hotel finder site and want to filter my search results by custom fields when the user searches a location. So for example when a user types in 'London' it will find hotels in London based on some custom fields they have added. But it only works when the search is `example.com/?s=` if I search a location like `example.com/?s=London` my pagination doesn't show. But if I add no location and leave the search blank like `example.com/?s=` pagination shows and works correctly. Would anyone know why? I'm not that great at php so I really need some help. My current search.php file looks like this.

```
<?php $unique_id = esc_attr( uniqid( 'search-form-' ) ); ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

    <input type="search" id="<?php echo $unique_id; ?>" class="search-field" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>

<?php $searchm = get_search_query(); ?>


<?php if ( get_search_query() == '' ): ?>

<?php 

$args_a = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'CurrentLocation',
            'value'   => array($areauserwants, areauserwants2),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'AreaLookingFor',
            'value'   => $areaihave,
            'type'    => '',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
                array(
            'key' => 'NumberOfBeds',
            'value'   => $howmanybedsdoiwant,
            'type'    => '',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
array(
            'key' => 'TypeOfHotel',
            'value'   => $hoteltype,
            'type'    => '',
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
); ?>

<?php $query_a = new WP_Query( $args_a ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php   

 $args_a = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'CurrentLocation',
            'value'   => $searchm,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'AreaLookingFor',
            'value'   => $areaihave,
            'type'    => '',
            'compare' => '=',
                ),               
    ),
'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
); ?>

<?php $query_a = new WP_Query( $args_a ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $query_a->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>
<!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $query_a->have_posts() ) : $query_a->the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>  
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

<?php next_posts_link( 'Next', $custom_query->max_num_pages ); 
previous_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?>


    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'No homes matched your criteria' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: When you say "pagination", are you referring to the `Next` and `Previous` links? Or true pagination with page numbers / direct links to each page?

Comment: Yes next and previous links and if I manual try to go to page 2 I get a 404, if I do example.com/?s= it shows all posts and works correctly, but if I add a search like example.com/?s= I get no links and 404